# Importing English Dictionary Into a Python IDE

Tags: python

I am trying to import an English dictionary into either Spyder or PyCharm to be part of a small batch of code I have written.  I have tried three different methods, and, in both PyCharm and Spyder, the needed "modules(?)" fail to import.

Here are the three different methods I tried:

**1)**

```
import enchant

d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
```

**2)**

```
import json

collection = json.load(open("collection.json"))
```

**3)**

```
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary

dictionary=PyDictionary()
```

This is the result I get no matter which method I try and in both PyCharm and Spyder:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'enchant'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you made sure to install the enchant lib first:
`pip install pyenchant`
from a terminal

Then you should be able to just do:`import enchant`

Comment: no... I am new to this and saw the pip part, but couldn't figure out where to place it... I"ll try that.  Thanks~

Comment: Okay, I believe I am having the problem of the 32bit PyEnchant not beinhg able to work in the 64bit Python version.  So, I tried using PyDictionary; I was able to install it through pip.  I can get it to give definitions, but what I am trying to do is check if a random string of letters is a word. So, how do I simply find, let's say "lnty" is a word using PyDictionary (I used "dictionary = PyDictionar()) ?  As a test, I tried simply: ""good" in dictionary" and it get False.

Comment: Your follow up question is probably outside of the scope of the original question, and I am not familiar with either library to be honest, but maybe example 2 on this page can help: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/96876/PyDictionary.PyDictionary